# Overriding the mouseout handler for an image when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I had posted this question in Stack Overflow and they told me it would be better served on Code Review.

Is there a more effecient way of changing the mouseout state when a button is clicked? When a button is clicked I want the image in the click event to take precedence over the image in the mouseout event. The following code works but I'm not sure if nesting events is a good practice.

```
$("#targetBtn").on({
  "mouseover" : function() {
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'images/_hover.png');
  },
 "mouseout" : function() {
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'images/_mouseout.png');
 },
 "click" : function() {
   $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'images/_selected.png');
   $(this).mouseout(function() {
      $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'images/_selected.png');
   });
  }
});
```

If anyone could refactor this code and show me a better way of doing this it would be greatly appreciated. Also if someone could explain why nesting events is bad (if indeed it is) I would appreciate that as well.

Comment: Wait, why are you using jQuery and then just a few lines later using `querySelector`?

Comment: sorry. I'm new to` JQuery` and I was just told in `stackoverflow` that its a bad practice. Why is it a bad practice if `JQuery` is just a`= `Javascript` library?

Answer (score 7):

It is bad practice as you add a new handler each time your event is fired.

To better understand this, try this:

```js
$('p')
  .on('click', function(e) {
    console.log('1');
    $(this).on('click', function(e) {
      console.log('2');
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  click me
</p>
```

Each time you click "click me", it should log one more "2".

A better way is to refactor your code to use a flag

```
(function() {
    var flag = true;

    $('#targetBtn')
        .on('mouseover', function(e) {
            $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'images/_hover.png');
        })
        .on('mouseout', function(e) {
            if(flag)
                $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'images/_mouseout.png');
            else
                $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'images/_selected.png');

            // or
            // $(this).find('img').attr('src', (flag ? 'images/_mouseout.png' : 'images/_selected.png'));
        })
        .on('click', function(e) {
            flag = false;
            $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'images/_selected.png');
        });
})();
```

See this demonstration to grasp the result:

```js
(function() {
  var flag = true;

  $('#targetBtn')
    .on('mouseover', function(e) {
      console.log('src', 'images/_hover.png');
    })
    .on('mouseout', function(e) {
      if (flag)
        console.log('src', 'images/_mouseout.png');
      else
        console.log('src', 'images/_selected.png');

      // or
      //console.log('src', (flag ? 'images/_mouseout.png' : 'images/_selected.png'));
    })
    .on('click', function(e) {
      flag = false;
      console.log('src', 'images/_selected.png');
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="targetBtn">btn</a>
```

Comment: Awesome explained. I hope you write more here.

Comment: I would invert the sense of the `flag`, initialize it to `false`, and rename it to `buttonHasBeenClicked`.